# Prove: If finite automata M with k states accepts a string with at least k characters, then the language L(M) is infinite

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

I need to prove that if finite automata $M$ with $k$ states accepts a string with at least $k$ characters, then the language $L(M)$ is infinite. I have no idea where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: You start with the definitions of everything and what requirements fall through from one Y to it's equivalent X.

Comment: Are you familiar with the pumping lemma?

Comment: Try drawing a FA with, say, four states. What happens when you give it an input of four characters? Hint: repeat.

Comment: I am aware of pumping lemma, however I am still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: The proof is exactly the same as the pumping lemma's.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Consider a word a length $\geqslant k$ accepted by $M$ and a successful path for this word. Now prove that this path goes at least twice through the same state, thus producing a loop.